# Problem with jdbc mysql driver and signed apk Android Studio 4

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I state that it is essential for me to connect to mysql through the jdbc driver. It's an application that has been working like this for years.

If I run the application from Android Studio on my samsung j5 it works fine. If instead I compile the apk with the signature and install it on the same device I get this error message:

```
09-01 18:01:17.106 21570-21586/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: x.wifi, PID: 21570
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger
    at b.b.a.a0.x()
    at b.b.a.a0.<clinit>()
    at b.b.a.q1.connect()
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
    at x.Connessione.B0()
    at x.Connessione.u()
    at x.WifiActivity.H()
    at x.WifiActivity.O()
    at x.WifiActivity$d0.a()
    at x.WifiActivity$d0.doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "x.wifi"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 8
    versionName "1.7"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds true
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
       
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

}
}

dependencies {


androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.0.8'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}
```

proguard:

```
-keep public class com.mysql.* {*;}
-dontwarn com.mysql.**
```

I have already tried to include the connector jar in libs, obviously with the proper gradle script configuration but the result is the same.
Before the update of Android Studio from 4.0 to 4.0.1 and the update of gradle from 4 to 6 I compiled and installed the signed apk correctly without problems.
Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
-keep public class com.mysql.** {*;}
```

as the class that you are losing is in a deep sub-package under `com.mysql`, not directly in `com.mysql`.

If that does not help, try running some of [the troubleshooting reports](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#usage) and see if they give you any clues.

> it is essential for me to connect to mysql through the jdbc driver

With all due respect, just because you deem it to be essential does not mean that it is a sensible choice for most apps and developers. JDBC is ancient and was designed around clients and servers on a stable secured LAN. It was not designed for mobile devices. While you are welcome to use it, I always recommend that developers do something else.

Comment: This solution did not solve the problem. The error now is: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty

Comment: I solved it by modifying the rules of proguard and gradle. Notes: the application runs in protected lan;)!